# Heroku's npm can't see Mongoose 4.2.2

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose

I have this set in package.json, which works fine in localhost

```
{
   ...
   "mongoose": "4.x",
   "mongoose-auto-increment": "5.x"
   ...
}
```

At the time, install mongoose 4.2.2 and mongoose-auto-increment 5.0.1. Heroku logs are giving this:

```
   npm ERR! node v4.2.1
   npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
   npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

   npm ERR! peerinvalid The package mongoose@4.1.11 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!

   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1 wants mongoose@^4.1.12
```

it seems that Heroku uses a different outdated npm or heavily relies on cache? Because the mongoose 4.2.2 package was published in [npmjs.com](http://npmjs.com/package/mongoose) 16 hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku uses a cache that is just like your local `node_modules` directory. This is the same behavior you see locally by installing mongoose 4.1.11 first and then mongoose-auto-increment later:

```
v4.1.1:~/test/epeer$ npm install --save mongoose@4.1.11
...
v4.1.1:~/test/epeer$ npm install --save mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency mongoose@^4.1.12 included from mongoose-auto-increment will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/hloftis/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/node" "/Users/hloftis/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package mongoose@4.1.11 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1 wants mongoose@^4.1.12
```

Locally, you probably update one and then install the other, or even just `rm -rf node_modules`. On Heroku, you can disable the `node_modules` cache to get the same result:

```
$ heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku config:unset NODE_MODULES_CACHE
```

However, a *much* better technique is to specify exact dependencies instead of letting your app's dependencies drift. So instead of '4.x' just specify '4.2.2' and instead of '5.x' specify '5.0.1'. That way you know the packages you're developing and testing with are the exact same packages you're deploying - by using semver ranges, your dependency versions can change at any time to anything that satisfies the range.

Comment: thanks NODE_MODULES_CACHE did the trick. For bigger (and heavily maintained) modules, I just *trust* semver. That's why I'm using 5.x / 4.x instead of the exact version (and I usually update node_modules locally before any deploy as well)

Comment: It's less about trusting semver and more about having parity between all different environments in which an app is installed. For instance, with the current codebase, an `npm install` run next year will be totally different from one run today. As long as the app isn't in production, that can be okay, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is actually that the semver ranges specified here are *wrong*. They say "mongoose 4.anything will work alongside mongoose-auto-increment 5.anything" but that isn't true. mongoose 4.1.11 + mongoose-auto-increment 5.0.1 => failure.